# Audio via USB instead of Analog with Pulseaudio

Tags: debian, osx, raspbian, pulseaudio, pulseaudio-equalizer

Using a Mac mini Mid 2011 running Catalina and a Dell Inspiron Mini 1012 running Raspbian (Debian 4.9), I currently have a 3.5mm cable connecting Mac headphone port to dell mic port. Dell equalizes the sound using Qpaeq/Pulseaudio and then out to speakers. Having some quality issues so I want to run digital instead of analog. I want to use a Usb cable and run all the audio digitally from Mac to Dell instead of 3.5. What terminal commands do I need to do to the dell to set up a USB audio device and have it be recognized by the Mac as a possible output device?

Inspired from this article https://www.cnet.com/how-to/make-the-most-out-of-your-computers-usb-audio-port/